# How to mask two half images and on hover show a full image with an nice animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I doesn’t know how to do the following with jQuery.
I have created a page hero with two sections (red/black):

[image]

What I want is, when hovering over the black one for example, it will expand over the red section, so you get a full black box. The same result I want of course for the red section:

[image]

How should I make this work?

```
var redSection = $('#red');
var blackSection = $('#black');

redSection.on('mouseover', function() { 
    // Do something - overlay the other section
});
```

The HTML markup is as follow:

```
<section id="hero">
        <figure id="urbandesign">
            <a href=“#" target="_blank">
                <img src="images/urbandesign.jpg" alt="Urban Design">
            </a>
        </figure><!-- End figure -->

        <figure id="photography">
            <a href=“#" target="_blank">
                <img src="images/photography.jpg" alt="Photography">
            </a>
        </figure><!-- End figure -->

    </section><!-- End section#hero -->
```

And the CSS:

```
#hero {
    height: 480px; /* Default 500px */
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    background: url(../images/hero.jpg) no-repeat center; /* remove */

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
}

#hero figure {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: #FFF;
}

#hero img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

The final result I want to replace the red and black section with images.
Look out to your response! Thank you.

Comment: what is the html/css for this page ?

Comment: See updated question. Forget it to paste it in the question! @elio.d

Answer (score 2):

A mix of CSS3 and jQuery with Graceful Degradation should sort this.

**CSS**

```
.page {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.black {
    background:#000;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:-50%;
    transform:skew(30deg,0);
    transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index:1;
}
.red {
    background:#ff0000;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    right:-50%;
    transform:skew(30deg,0);
    transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.red:hover {
    transform:skew(0);
    transform:translate(-50%,0);
}
.black:hover {
    transform:skew(0);
    transform:translate(50%,0);   
}
.inactive {
    z-index:-1
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

The jQuery is necessary to fix a z-index problem with the last element in the DOM tree that ruins the fluid animation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.black').hover(function(){
        $('.red').addClass('inactive');
    },function(){
        $('.red').removeClass('inactive');
    });
     $('.red').hover(function(){
        $('.black').addClass('inactive');
    },function(){
        $('.black').removeClass('inactive');
    });
});
```

Be aware that adding any content to the two divs you will have to add an inner div and reset the skew with 'transform:skew(-30deg,0);'. The prefixed versions of transition and transform will also need adding.

[JSFiddle Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/asherstoppard/r134x65e/24/)

Comment: Animation using `left` \ `right` isn't the best choice from the performance point of view. Read [here](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)

Comment: I've amended animation using left / right to translate, there would need to be some graceful degradation implemented for IE8 and Opera Mini (if required) - http://caniuse.com/#search=transform.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using `svg`'s `path` for the shape, `pattern` for the `image` and a little bit of JavaScript for handling the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events.

```js
var hero = document.getElementById('hero');
var animLeft = document.getElementById('anim-left');
var animRight = document.getElementById('anim-right');
hero.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  (e.target.id == 'left') ? animRight.beginElement() : animLeft.beginElement();
})
hero.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
  (e.target.id == 'left') ? animRight.endElement() : animLeft.endElement();
})
```

```html
<svg id="hero" width="600" height="200" viewBox="0 0 600 200">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image-left" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="600" height="200" viewBox="0 0 600 200">
      <image xlink:href="http://dummyimage.com/600x200/40000c/000" width="600" height="200" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="image-right" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="600" height="200" viewBox="0 0 600 200">
      <image xlink:href="http://dummyimage.com/600x200/002a33/fff" width="600" height="200" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <path id="right" d="M0,0 h600 v200 h-600z" fill="url(#image-right)" />
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <path id="left" d="M0,0 h350 l-100,200 h-250z" fill="url(#image-left)" />
    <animate id="anim-left" xlink:href="#left" attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" from="M0,0 h350 l-100,200 h-250z" to="M0,0 h0 l-100,200 h0z" dur="1" begin="indefinite" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
    <animate id="anim-right" xlink:href="#left" attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" from="M0,0 h350 l-100,200 h-250z" to="M0,0 h700 l-100,200 h-600z" dur="1" begin="indefinite" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />

  </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: This one is very nice, the right shapes, but if it can combine with the answer of asherstoppard would be very nice, so two side can be moved, instead of one side..

Answer (score 0):

A simple CSS only solution with no additional re-paints, etc.:

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}
.item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  transition: transform 1s, z-index 1s;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item .image {
    transition: transform 1s;
}

.item:hover {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  z-index: 100;
}

.item:hover .image {
  transform: skewX(0deg);
}

.red {
  background: #f00;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 0px, 0px) skewX(-10deg);
}

.red .image {
  transform: skewX(10deg);
}

.black {
  background: #000;
  transform: translate3d(50%, 0px, 0px) skewX(-10deg);
}

.black img {
  transform: skewX(10deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="parent">
  <div class="red item">
    <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/450/ff0000/000000" />
  </div>
  <div class="black item">
    <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/450/000000/ffffff" />
  </div>
</section>
```